# checking if value is in array and returning the rest of the items

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

below is the array i have

```
  [{
    "Email": "alsongdunstan2@gmail.com",
    "SecretKey": "e868f7b4c5b3a7d23cc746d24fdb65aad7a0d762",
    "SecretIv": "dd760185b148d4a59e0adf583b21b15b8d6d7e16"
}, {
    "Email": "sule@gmail.com",
    "SecretKey": "d36c88178041cc1942b068bbd6dd0f2a88681dfb",
    "SecretIv": "33ead1d0267e99eff90aac18a1c848fbcb1253b2"
}, {
    "Email": "alsongdunstan@gmail.com",
    "SecretKey": "45bf3e3dd6efb9022606c1ed095b033daf0a1d3d",
    "SecretIv": "74528bdb8418522d1ff1a37e4ca9db1e0dc160da"
}]
```

i want to be able to search if sule@gmail.com is in the array above.
and then return the secretkey and secretiv values.

the code below is what am trying to do

```
    <?php
include_once '../Includes/Secure.php';
include_once '../Includes/ConnectionInfo.php';

/*Acquiring the security class*/
$mSecure = new Includes\Secure;
$mConnectionInfo = new Includes\ConnectionInfo();
$mConnectionInfo->GetConnection();

$email ="sule@gmail.com";

if ($mConnectionInfo->conn){
    echo "is connected <br/>";

    $stmt2 = $mConnectionInfo->conn->prepare('SELECT email, secret_key, secret_iv FROM users');

    $work2 = $stmt2->execute();
    $returnedvalue = array();
    if ($work2){
        while($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $secret_key = $row['secret_key'];
            $secret_iv = $row['secret_iv'];

            $secret_key = $mSecure->my_simple_crypt_key($row['secret_key'],'d','sha384');//encrypt with sha384

            $secret_iv = $mSecure->my_simple_crypt_key($row['secret_iv'],'d','sha384');//encrypt with sha384


            $decryptedemail = $mSecure->my_simple_crypt($row['email'],'d','sha384',$secret_key,$secret_iv);//encrypt with sha384

            $value = ["Email" => $decryptedemail, "SecretKey" => $secret_key, "SecretIv" => $secret_iv];
            array_push($returnedvalue, $value);
        }

        echo json_encode($returnedvalue);
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $email;

        if(in_array($email,$returnedvalue,TRUE)){
            echo "<br/> value exists";
        }
        else{
            echo "<br/> value doesnt exists<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

need some help on how to check if the value exists and how to retrieve the other elements associated with the value.

or if there is another way to do it, thanks

Comment: Why not just add `WHERE email = :email` to your query? Here, you're selecting every single row just to check for one value.

Comment: Is this your friend - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860873/unable-to-check-whether-value-exists-in-array

Answer (score -1):

You should use a foreach loop directly on the output of the execution of the PDO, like so

```
if ($mConnectionInfo->conn){

echo "is connected <br/>";

$stmt2 = $mConnectionInfo->conn->prepare('SELECT email, secret_key, secret_iv FROM users');
$stmt2 = execute();

foreach($stmt2 as $row){

    if($email == $mSecure->my_simple_crypt($row['email'],'d','sha384',$secret_key,$secret_iv);){

        $secret_key = $row['secret_key'];
        $secret_iv = $row['secret_iv'];
        $secret_iv = $mSecure->my_simple_crypt_key($row['secret_iv'],'d','sha384');//encrypt with sha384
        $decryptedemail = $mSecure->my_simple_crypt($row['email'],'d','sha384',$secret_key,$secret_iv);//encrypt with sha384
        $value = ["Email" => $decryptedemail, "SecretKey" => $secret_key, "SecretIv" => $secret_iv];

        array_push($returnedvalue, $secret_key);
        array_push($returnedvalue, $secret_iv);
        array_push($returnedvalue, $secret_iv);
        array_push($returnedvalue, $decryptedemail);
        array_push($returnedvalue, $value);
    }
}

    echo json_encode($returnedvalue);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $email;

    if(in_array($email,$returnedvalue,TRUE)){
        echo "<br/> value exists";
    }
    else{
        echo "<br/> value doesnt exists<br/>";
    }
}
```

}
?>

Comment: the email in database has to be decrypted inorder to check if the passed email value is equal to one in the array